# Is initialization-on-demand holder idiom still safe if parameterized?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, singleton

If I modified [the stock initialization-on-demand holder idiom example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) like this:

```
public class Something {

    //internal params, unchangeable after the initialization
    private final List<String> params;

    //changeable params that will be used for initialization
    private final static List<String> initParams = new ArrayList<>();

    private Something(List<String> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    //allow params to be added prior to initialization
    public static void addParam(String param) {
        initParams.add(param);
    }

    private static class LazyHolder {
        static final Something INSTANCE =
            new Something(Collections.unmodifiableList(initParams));
    }

    public static Something getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public int calculate() {
       return params.size(); //use the internal params somehow
    }
}
```

And used as follows:

- Only 1 thread calls `addParam` multiple times to prepare the initialization (the only *writing* thread)
- Many threads (that may have been created before the *writing* thread) later call `getInstance` to obtain the singleton instance (many *reading* threads)
- The initial call to `getInstance` could be performed by either the *writing* thread or one of the *reading* threads

Is this usage safe (albeit convoluted)?
**Does anything change depending on which thread (reader or writer) first calls `getInstance`?**
**Does anything change if the static `initParams` variable is made `volatile`?**

If the first call is performed by a *reading* thread (created before the *writing* thread), can its internal view of `initParams` be outdated and cause the initialized instance to be outdated as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this usage safe (albeit convoluted)?

No, I don't think you have any guarantees, in the question as currently stated, that the first call to `getInstance` will happen-after the last call to `addParam`.

You do say that the first call to `getInstance` will happen "later", but you then qualify that by saying that "[the reader threads] may have been created before the writing thread", which makes me think that you can't guarantee this order.

If you can guarantee this "happens-after" relation between the init and the reads, then I think this is thread safe, yes, for the same reason that the simpler version is.

> Does anything change depending on which thread (reader or writer) first calls getInstance?

Yes, if the writer thread is the first to call `getInstance`, then things should be thread-safe. That is because its writes to the global variable `initParams` are guaranteed to happen-before later reads on the same thread.

However, this is basically the same guarantee I discussed above, so I think this is just moving things around.

> Does anything change if the static initParams variable is made volatile?

That would help to narrow the race between the first call to `getInstance` and the last call to `addParam`, but I think you are still relying on the latter happening "after" the former.

#### Taking a step back

This design is fragile, complex and ugly. You are using a global variable "`initParams`" and relying on some very tricky side-effects and ordering.

You say that you have a "writer thread" which builds up the "Something" instance and that "later" it will be read.

Can you not re-arrange things so that all the writing happens strictly before the reading starts, and stop using static variables entirely?

Comment: I've slightly modified the question to better highlight my doubts. Please see the bolded parts. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I have updated in response. I think this question has been abstracted / anonymised to the point where the answer is not very interesting. This doesn't seem like a good thing to be trying to do.

Comment: Great, thanks! I, of course, agree this design is pretty much insane, and would never actually use it. I just somehow got into a discussion about what would happen in this theoretical case and really wanted to untangle it in my brain. That's why it's abstract, it's not an actual case I have, just a thought experiment :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not thread-safe. You lose the happens before ordering since you introduce writing to a shared variable which is not guarded by the thread-safe class loading.

The scenario would be

```
Thread 1: Write Thread
   read initParams
   initParams.add(param)

Thread 2: First read thread
   synchronized(class_loader_lock){ 
      load class
      read initParams
   }
```

Thread 1's writes, since not synchronized with the class loading, therefore can be read stale.

Comment: I've slightly modified the question to better highlight my doubts. Please see the bolded parts. Thanks!