# how to design lazy holder pattern in android with arguments?

Tags: android

I wanna know how to design lazyholder singleton pattern with arguments.
I know only when no argument there is but dont know with arguments.
the problem is like below when construct `private static final DBHelper INSTANCE = new DBHelper();`
how can I solve it?

```
  public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        this.context=context;
    }

    public static DBHelper getInstance(){
        return DBHelper.DBHelperHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class  DBHelperHolder{
        private static final DBHelper INSTANCE = new DBHelper();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is initialization-on-demand holder idiom still safe if parameterized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557976/is-initialization-on-demand-holder-idiom-still-safe-if-parameterized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DCL pattert, for example:

```
public class DBHelper {
    private static volatile DBHelper instance;
    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (DBHelper .class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new DBHelper(context, name, factory, version);
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

But you need to supply arguments every time you call `getInstance`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Bracadabra's answer,

- It is recommended to add `private constructor()` as it is singleton pattern and we want to restrict new object creation of our class `DBHelper`
- I prefer `LOCK` object for `synchronisation` (to be thread safe)
- We should restrict `clone()` calls also, so that outside code can not clone this class by `.clone()` call. So, override `clone()` method and return `CloneNotSupportedException()` from it.

  ```
  public class DBHelper {

  private static DBHelper instance;

  // LOCK object for synchronisation
  private static Object LOCK = new Object();

  // Private Constructor
  private DBHelper() { }

  public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context, String name, 
      SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
      if (instance == null) {
          synchronized (LOCK) {
              if (instance == null) {
                  instance = new DBHelper(context, name, factory, version);
              }
          }
      }
      return instance;
  }

  @Override
  protected DBHelper clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
      return CloneNotSupportedException();
  }
  ```

Comment: If my answer solved your question, please accept my answer. Thanks